# Problem with midi setup on Raspberry Pi with midi board for RPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, midi, gpio, midi-interface, pigpio

I bought this one from osa electronics:
https://www.osaelectronics.com/product/midi-board-for-raspberry-pi/

I followed the instructions here on how to set it up:
https://www.osaelectronics.com/learn/setting-up-raspberry-pi-for-midi/

After following the setup and running this in command line:

```
python
import mido
mido.get_output_names()
```

It outputs this which seems to be correct:

> ['Midi Through:Midi Through Port-0 14:0', 'f_midi:f_midi 24:0']

as well as when I run this from command line:

```
amidi -l
```

outputs this:

```
Dir Device    Name
IO  hw:2,0    f_midi
```

However when I run some test applications from their webapge I get no input or output.
like this one:

```
import mido
from mido import MidiFile
from mido import MetaMessage
port = mido.open_output('f_midi')
mid = MidiFile('mymidifile.mid')

while True:
    for msg in MidiFile('mymidifile.mid').play():
        port.send(msg)
```

or from this one (I tried to print the msg but it wont print it even. So doesnt seem to step into the while loop but no errormessages)

```
import mido
import pigpio
from numpy import interp

pi1 = pigpio.pi()

port = mido.open_input('f_midi')  # open USB port

while True:
    try:  # This filters out all non-note data
        for msg in port.iter_pending():  # if there is a message pending
            print(msg)
            if(msg.type == 'note_on'):  # if it is Note On message
                out = interp(msg.velocity, [0, 127], [0, 255])
#scale velocity from 0-127 to 0-255
                # filter the data by note number
                if(msg.note == 53):
                    pi1.set_PWM_dutycycle(2, out)
                elif(msg.note == 55):
                    pi1.set_PWM_dutycycle(3, out)
                elif(msg.note == 57):
                    pi1.set_PWM_dutycycle(4, out)
            else:  # if the message is not Note On (e.g. Note Off)
                if(msg.note == 53):
                    pi1.set_PWM_dutycycle(2, 0)
                elif(msg.note == 55):
                    pi1.set_PWM_dutycycle(3, 0)
                elif(msg.note == 57):
                    pi1.set_PWM_dutycycle(4, 0)
    except AttributeError as error:
        print("Error excepted")
        pass
```

I noticed there is some problems with pigpio daemon
After I have been downloading and installed from this page:
http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/download.html

And then try to start the daemon with:

```
sudo pigpiod
```

I get this errormessage:

> bind to port 8888 failed (Address already in use) Can't initialise
> pigpio library

However I have also been running through with this in command line:

```
aplaymidi -p f_midi myMidiTune.mid
```

No errormessage but no midioutput to my digital piano ...

How can I debug this?

Comment: did you find find a solution eventually?

Comment: unfortunately not. and not a word when contacting the support ...